# Example of a continuous, atomless and strictly increasing density over an unbounded support

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function, monotone-functions

Consider a continuous variable with support $\mathbb{R}$ and density $f$. For every bounded interval belonging to $\mathbb{R}$, $f$ must be bounded (by continuity). If $f$ is strictly increasing in its unbounded support, then the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f\left(x\right)$ must not exist (otherwise $f$ would not integrate to $1$).

Is there a concrete example of such an $f$, i.e. continuous, atomless and *strictly increasing* density over an *unbounded* support? I think I was able to find such a distribution by prior search in a book but I can't find it anymore and would appreciate any directions.

Comment: How could such a function be integrable?

Comment: Good point, it should be bounded, but I still recall an example. My point is that a strictly increasing density must imply that the support is bounded. I am curious to see if this could happen when the support is unbounded (and for that case we should at least assume that the limit at the end of the support does not exist).

Comment: As pointed out by Math1000 such a function would not be integrable and hence cannot be a density function.

Comment: [I found that book! Please see Section 2.7](https://books.google.com/books?id=BodHDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT64&dq=a+continuous+density+that+does+not+tend+asymptotically+to+zero&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqhandxtHbAhVBwlkKHRXTA2oQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=a%20continuous%20density%20that%20does%20not%20tend%20asymptotically%20to%20zero&f=false) and would appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what there is no such density, but the "closest" answer to my question is an example of a continuous density that does not asymptotically tend to zero. [I am aware of this example](https://books.google.com/books?id=BodHDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT64&dq=a%20continuous%20density%20that%20does%20not%20tend%20asymptotically%20to%20zero&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqhandxtHbAhVBwlkKHRXTA2oQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=a%20continuous%20density%20that%20does%20not%20tend%20asymptotically%20to%20zero&f=false) from Section 2.7 in the book "Counterexamples in Probability And Statistics", Chapman & Hall/CRC, 1986 by Romano and Siegel. If you know other examples please post them below for future reference.